github sign in popup keeps appearing in vscode
vscode shows me a popup every time I want to push commits to github.
When I close the popup, then still the commits are pushed, so my credentials must be known. I'm not even sure which credentials are used. It might be the code of 'sign in with a code' which I've done before or the SSH credentials I've tried to configure.
How can I prevent this popup from showing up?


This question is similar to: How to disable github login in vscode. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ZacAnger it is different. I tried the solution mentioned and it got worse :) The popup stayed, but when I close it, it asks me for username/password

Looks like there's also "git.useIntegratedAskPass" which might be worth setting to false. Full list of options is here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/main/docs/getstarted/settings.md?plain=1#L5263

@ZacAnger that's not having any effect
